# Linq The sum of hourly data?

Tags: c#, linq

There are hourly data is captured in my table. I want to sum of these data for a day. For example

this is my table data

```
| date             | value |

| 12.03.2010 01.pm |    10 |
| 12.03.2010 02.pm |    20 |
| 12.03.2010 03.pm |    15 |
| 13.03.2010 04.pm |    15 |
| 13.03.2010 05.pm |    25 |
| 13.03.2010 08.pm |    35 |
```

And I want to get sum of values in a day.

```
12.03.2010 total_usage = 45
12.03.2010 total_usage = 75
```

How Can I do this. How can I get sum of hourly data in a day.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myCollection.GroupBy(x => x.date.Date).Select(x => new { Date= x.Key, Total = x.Sum(y => y.value) });
```

Comment: I think i will not ignore the time.

Comment: @Asif The value is needed for the day i.e a Date so should be fine

Comment: @Asif yes if date property is DateTime type it should be grouped by DateTime.Date property. Edited for corectness

Answer (score 4):

> I dont say write codes for me

You can do it through `Linq` using `GroupBy` and `Sum()`.

Comment: I asked somewhat similar question yesterday, and users downvote my question. They said, you should work to do it.so, Now I write this notice :) Thanks